# Почему jQuery не убирает все, а остается в левой части фрагмент страницы?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Идея такая: имеются 2 слоя - верхний и нижний. При нажатии на кнопку внизу страницы jQuery со 100% уменьшает первый слой до 0%.

Проблема: он убирает все, а после опять возвращает 1 фрагмент, т.е в левой части образуется панель. Как сделать, чтобы она не возвращалась? Убралась и все

Вот ссылка: http://jsfiddle.net/sU8v2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

После того как оно стало шириной в 0, [Делаем ее невидимой](http://jsfiddle.net/IVsevolod/sU8v2/1/)

```
$('#button').click(function(){
    $('#step1_page').animate({
        'width' : '0%'
    }, 1000,function(){
        $(this).hide();
    })
})
```